# Powershell commands only work when importing CSV - 365

Tags: powershell, office365

I am attempting to add a member to a 365 Distribution Group using Powershell. The following is not working:

`Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Testing" -Member firstname.surname@contoso.com`

The following IS working:

`Import-Csv "C:\GroupCreation.csv" | foreach{Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.identity -Member $_.member}`

The contents of the CSV are:

> ```
> Identity,Member
> Testing,firstname.surname@contoso.com
> ```

I have tried with and without quotation marks around the group name, the Member e-mail address together and individually.

No error at all, just does not appear in the group.

-WhatIf:

What if: Adding distribution group member "firstname.surname@contoso.com" on distribution group "Testing"

Any help appreciated

Comment: Try putting quotes around the `firstname.surname@contoso.com`.

Comment: If you are getting an error message when you try it manually, please include that message in your question.

Comment: I have updated the original post to cover both of these